# How do grant rw access to public folder in laravel

Tags: laravel

I get this error after i migrated my project from windows to mac.

The "/private/var/folders/6w/zypn4xb120l6x6f1kjx9_nxw0000gn/T/phpwroBVT" file does not exist or is not readable.

here is my code

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images/services');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $image_name);

        $summary = $request->summary;
        $body = $request->body;
        $title = $request->title;

       $service = Service::create([
            'title'=> $title,
            'summary'=>$summary,
            'body'=>$body,
            'image'=> $image
        ]

        );
        if($service){
            return redirect()->back()->with('success','services added');
        }

    }
```

the images goes into the public/images/services folder but i get the above error

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar error and I found out that i was accessing the global variable declared in the controller without "this" pointer reference. For example

`class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public $attachment_folder_name = "/blogs/";
}`

You should access this variable with following syntax.

```
echo $this->attachment_folder_name
```

And not like this

`echo $attachment_folder_name`